# Refactor mysql query into one so no need to have 2 connections

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to combine these queries into one? 
so that I will not create another connection just in case the conditions matched.

```
$sql1 = "select status,ext_status from dnd where ext =:ext  order by no desc limit 1 ";
$query =  $this->db->prepare($sql1);
$query->execute(array(':ext' => $ext));
$result = $query->fetch();

if($result['status'] != '')
{
    $status_no = $result['status'];
}
else
{
    if($result['ext_status'] == '51')
    {
        $sql2 = "select ext,status from dnd where ext =:ext2 and status != '' order by no desc limit 1";
        $query2 =  $this->db->prepare($sql2);
        $query2->execute(array(':ext2' => $ext));
        $result2 = $query2->fetch();

        if($result2) {
            $status_no = $result2['status'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $status_no = $statusActual;
    }
}

return $status_no;
```

Edit:
Here's a sample data from the table:

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------+------+------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+----------+
| no    | date                | date_ext            | ext  | status | etc1 | etc2 | etc3 | ext_status | datetime            | answer_time | hangup_time | src  | did  | uniqueid |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------+------+------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+----------+
| 19103 | 2019-01-01 02:59:46 | 2019-01-01 02:59:46 | 6603 |        | NULL | NULL | NULL | 52         | 2019-01-01 02:59:46 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19104 | 2019-01-01 08:56:37 | 2019-01-01 08:56:37 | 6601 |        | NULL | NULL | NULL | 52         | 2019-01-01 08:56:37 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19105 | 2019-01-01 08:56:38 | 2019-01-01 08:56:38 | 6601 |        | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51         | 2019-01-01 08:56:38 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19106 | 2019-01-01 09:19:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 6601 | 31     | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51         | 2019-01-01 09:19:00 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19107 | 2019-01-01 10:24:19 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 6601 | 32     | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51         | 2019-01-01 10:24:19 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19108 | 2019-01-01 11:57:36 | 2019-01-01 11:57:36 | 6601 | 21     | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51         | 2019-01-01 11:57:36 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19109 | 2019-01-01 13:05:12 | 2019-01-01 13:05:12 | 6601 | 22     | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51         | 2019-01-01 13:05:12 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19110 | 2019-01-01 16:59:20 | 2019-01-01 16:59:20 | 6601 |        | NULL | NULL | NULL | 52         | 2019-01-01 16:59:20 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19111 | 2019-01-01 17:00:26 | 2019-01-01 17:00:26 | 6601 |        | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51         | 2019-01-01 17:00:26 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
| 19112 | 2019-01-01 17:15:20 | 2019-01-01 17:15:20 | 6601 | 11     | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51         | 2019-01-01 17:15:20 | NULL        | NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL     |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------+------+------+------+------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+----------+
```

Let's say, I want to get the status of ext = 6601,
I currently query like this:

```
select status,ext_status from dnd where ext =:ext  order by no desc limit 1
```

If the result has status != '' (empty), I will use the result's query,
but if status == '' and ext_status == '51', I need to re-query using this to get the status:

```
select ext,status from dnd where ext =:ext2 and status != '' order by no desc limit 1
```

I have an idea on a query, but unfortunately, it doesn't working.

```
SELECT 
    CASE ext_status = 51 THEN (SELECT STATUS FROM dnd WHERE ext = '8001' AND STATUS != '' ORDER BY NO DESC LIMIT 1)
    ELSE STATUS END AS test
FROM dnd WHERE ext = '8001'  ORDER BY NO DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yes, it's certainly possible to combine these two queries into one. But it's hard to reverse-engineer your specification from your code. Please [edit] your question to say more about what you are doing, and maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   d.status,
   d.ext_status,
   COALESCE(d2.status, d.status) test
FROM dnd d
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT ext, status 
   FROM dnd
   ORDER BY no DESC) d2
ON d.ext = d2.ext
   AND d2.status != ''
   AND d.ext_status = 51
WHERE d.ext = :ext 
ORDER BY no DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for taking the time to answer. Though when I test the query above, It's very slow, I think it is because on left join. As the statement returns > 3000 of data. It led me to this query:

SELECT
   d.status,
   d.ext_status,
   COALESCE(d2.status, d.status) test
FROM dnd d
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT ext, status 
   FROM dnd
   where ext = :ext
   and status != ''
   ORDER BY no DESC limit 1) d2
ON d.ext = d2.ext
WHERE d.ext = :ext 
ORDER BY no DESC
LIMIT 1

I will test it more to check if data returned were correct,
Thank you again.

Comment: @sylvan016 it is slow not because of `COALESCE` but because of subquery. It was just a demo of what you probably need as an example.
You should provide your table schema and the logic of how you store data. Slowness come from the `OREDER BY` in subquery. So technically if the solution works for you in terms of resulted dataset we can work to adjust it to fix performance issue.

Comment: Hello @Alex , This is the test database that I'm working on:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlTfNEMo0vDRwBUkNw4N17xhI7p_?e=paeAqd

Unfortunately, I cannot provide you how to insert data, as I myself do not know, they just gave me access on this database on our company.